# After Feature Update Windows 10 won't sleep (powercfg of no help)

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

Yet another Windows won't sleep thread, I'm afraid...

**Running Windows 10 v1909 and all is fine**.  Monitors shut down and later computer sleeps per the power configuration set.  All device drivers are up to date (via vendor when available, Microsoft when not). BIOS is at latest version, albeit several years old now (motherboard manufacturers don't seem to want to support hardware past a year or so any more).

Last year I tried the feature update to v2004.  **Immediately after the Feature Update computer no longer powered down monitors or went to sleep.**  Even if I left it on the login screen right after a reboot, it wouldn't sleep. So I'm certain it isn't Chrome or one of the other usual app suspects.

I tried the old `powercfg /requests` method to try to find out what may be keeping it awake and all come back as "None".

Restored back to v1909 and sleep went back to normal.

Fast forward to late last year, tried v20H2 hoping that maybe the problem was fixed.  Nope.  After months of sleeping just fine under v1909, computer no longer sleeps after the update.

Restored back to v1909 and all is well again.  Kept the computer on 1909, installing all necessary updates to Windows as well as new device drivers.  No issues at all, monitor power down and sleep both work.

It's now May 2021, and a new feature update has been released. I install v21H1, and again same issue.  Monitors won't power down, computer won't sleep.  I again check `powercfg /requests` and all entries display 'None'.  I've reduced the monitor power down and sleep timers to 3 minutes to reduce chances of some occasional process keeping computer awake, but no no difference.

Pressing the sleep button in the keyboard works fine, and computer remains asleep (no unexpected wake ups), and waking up works fine.

At this point I'm at a loss.  The only two paths I can think is disabling all non-critical devices in DM and if that fails doing a clean install.  Before embarking on that path, I would love to hear any other suggestions people may have.

Thanks!

---

Diagnostics so far:

**As a reminder sleep worked fine under v1909 prior to the Feature Update being installed and stopped working immediately after the Feature Update was installed (tried separately going from 1909 to 2004 or 20H2 or 21H1). Reverting to 1909 everything allows sleep to work just fine.**

`powercfg /requests` - All entries say `None`

`powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostics` - Error results: "No sleep trace files exist. Put the machine to sleep for several minutes, then try again." Manually putting the computer to sleep still results in this error"

Rebooted system in safe mode.  Safe mode does not allow changing of sleep settings but does have a timer for turning off displays.  Timer for turning off displays was set to 5 minutes, but displays never turned off. (and system never went to sleep, of course)

`powercfg /a` indicates that Standby (S3), Hibernate, and Fast Startup are available.  It states that Hybrid is not available due to hypervisor.  I thought I had hybrid sleep available prior to update (in v1909) but I can't be certain without restoring system to previous version.

`powercfg -energy` has one suspect entry about "PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) has been disabled due to  known incompatibility with the hardware in this computer."  I do NOT recall whether the same issue manifested itself prior to the Feature Update when the computer WAS able to go to sleep.  [This old question (Windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/823548/what-is-the-known-hardware-incompatibility-that-disables-pcie-active-state-pow) seems to point to perhaps a USB component, although none of my components have changed.  Will unplug all to see what happens.

`powercfg /q` output:

```
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
  GUID Alias: SCHEME_BALANCED
  Subgroup GUID: 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442  (Hard disk)
    GUID Alias: SUB_DISK
    Power Setting GUID: 6738e2c4-e8a5-4a42-b16a-e040e769756e  (Turn off hard disk after)
      GUID Alias: DISKIDLE
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x000004b0
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000258

  Subgroup GUID: 02f815b5-a5cf-4c84-bf20-649d1f75d3d8  (Internet Explorer)
    Power Setting GUID: 4c793e7d-a264-42e1-87d3-7a0d2f523ccd  (JavaScript Timer Frequency)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Maximum Power Savings
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Maximum Performance
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

  Subgroup GUID: 0d7dbae2-4294-402a-ba8e-26777e8488cd  (Desktop background settings)
    Power Setting GUID: 309dce9b-bef4-4119-9921-a851fb12f0f4  (Slide show)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Available
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Paused
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

  Subgroup GUID: 19cbb8fa-5279-450e-9fac-8a3d5fedd0c1  (Wireless Adapter Settings)
    Power Setting GUID: 12bbebe6-58d6-4636-95bb-3217ef867c1a  (Power Saving Mode)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Maximum Performance
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Low Power Saving
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Medium Power Saving
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Maximum Power Saving
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000002

  Subgroup GUID: 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20  (Sleep)
    GUID Alias: SUB_SLEEP
    Power Setting GUID: 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da  (Sleep after)
      GUID Alias: STANDBYIDLE
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000708
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000384

    Power Setting GUID: 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e  (Allow hybrid sleep)
      GUID Alias: HYBRIDSLEEP
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Off
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: On
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

    Power Setting GUID: 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364  (Hibernate after)
      GUID Alias: HIBERNATEIDLE
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d  (Allow wake timers)
      GUID Alias: RTCWAKE
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Disable
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Enable
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Important Wake Timers Only
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

  Subgroup GUID: 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3  (USB settings)
    Power Setting GUID: 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226  (USB selective suspend setting)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Disabled
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Enabled
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: a7066653-8d6c-40a8-910e-a1f54b84c7e5  (Start menu power button)
      GUID Alias: UIBUTTON_ACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

  Subgroup GUID: 501a4d13-42af-4429-9fd1-a8218c268e20  (PCI Express)
    GUID Alias: SUB_PCIEXPRESS
    Power Setting GUID: ee12f906-d277-404b-b6da-e5fa1a576df5  (Link State Power Management)
      GUID Alias: ASPM
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Off
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Moderate power savings
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Maximum power savings
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000002

  Subgroup GUID: 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00  (Processor power management)
    GUID Alias: SUB_PROCESSOR
    Power Setting GUID: 893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964c  (Minimum processor state)
      GUID Alias: PROCTHROTTLEMIN
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000005
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000005

    Power Setting GUID: 94d3a615-a899-4ac5-ae2b-e4d8f634367f  (System cooling policy)
      GUID Alias: SYSCOOLPOL
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Passive
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Active
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: bc5038f7-23e0-4960-96da-33abaf5935ec  (Maximum processor state)
      GUID Alias: PROCTHROTTLEMAX
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000064
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000064

  Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99  (Display)
    GUID Alias: SUB_VIDEO
    Power Setting GUID: 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e  (Turn off display after)
      GUID Alias: VIDEOIDLE
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x0000012c
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x0000012c

    Power Setting GUID: aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb  (Display brightness)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000064
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000028

    Power Setting GUID: f1fbfde2-a960-4165-9f88-50667911ce96  (Dimmed display brightness)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000032
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000032

    Power Setting GUID: fbd9aa66-9553-4097-ba44-ed6e9d65eab8  (Enable adaptive brightness)
      GUID Alias: ADAPTBRIGHT
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Off
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: On
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

  Subgroup GUID: 9596fb26-9850-41fd-ac3e-f7c3c00afd4b  (Multimedia settings)
    Power Setting GUID: 03680956-93bc-4294-bba6-4e0f09bb717f  (When sharing media)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Allow the computer to sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Prevent idling to sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Allow the computer to enter Away Mode
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: 10778347-1370-4ee0-8bbd-33bdacaade49  (Video playback quality bias)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Video playback power-saving bias
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Video playback performance bias
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: 34c7b99f-9a6d-4b3c-8dc7-b6693b78cef4  (When playing video)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Optimize video quality
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Balanced
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Optimize power savings
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

  Subgroup GUID: e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f  (Battery)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BATTERY
    Power Setting GUID: 5dbb7c9f-38e9-40d2-9749-4f8a0e9f640f  (Critical battery notification)
      GUID Alias: BATFLAGSCRIT
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Off
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: On
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

    Power Setting GUID: 637ea02f-bbcb-4015-8e2c-a1c7b9c0b546  (Critical battery action)
      GUID Alias: BATACTIONCRIT
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000002
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000002

    Power Setting GUID: 8183ba9a-e910-48da-8769-14ae6dc1170a  (Low battery level)
      GUID Alias: BATLEVELLOW
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x0000000a
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x0000000a

    Power Setting GUID: 9a66d8d7-4ff7-4ef9-b5a2-5a326ca2a469  (Critical battery level)
      GUID Alias: BATLEVELCRIT
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000005
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000005

    Power Setting GUID: bcded951-187b-4d05-bccc-f7e51960c258  (Low battery notification)
      GUID Alias: BATFLAGSLOW
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Off
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: On
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

    Power Setting GUID: d8742dcb-3e6a-4b3c-b3fe-374623cdcf06  (Low battery action)
      GUID Alias: BATACTIONLOW
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: f3c5027d-cd16-4930-aa6b-90db844a8f00  (Reserve battery level)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000007
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000007
```

Comment: `powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostics`.

Comment: sleep system diagnostics won't run.  Get the error: "No sleep trace files exist. Put the machine to sleep for several minutes, then try again."  Manually putting the computer to sleep still results in this error

Comment: Edit your question with that extra information. Also add the output of `powercfg /q > clip` (this puts it on the clipboard as text to paste).

Comment: Does this behavior happen while in safe mode? Your system appears to be configured to hibernate not sleep which, I assume your system, is NOT attempting to hibernate?  What power mode are you setting your machine to?

Comment: @ramhound - I'll have to check on safe mode when I have time to reboot.  I'm not sure why you think system is set up to hibernate.  In PowerOptions-->Advanced Settings, I have "sleep after" times for both battery and plugged in, and "never" for Hibernate other than for "critical batter action"

Comment: You are set to sleep after 30 mins. Have you left it for 30 mins. Try turning off Hybrid Sleep. That writes a hibernation file, in case of power loss, then it sleeps. It is off by default in laptops because - *Laptop manufacturers also requested that hybrid sleep be off by default. They didn’t want the hard drive to be active for a long time while the system is suspending, because when users suspend a laptop, it’s often in the form of “Close the lid, pick up the laptop from the desk, throw it into a bag, head out.”* from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110510-00/?p=10703.

Comment: “I'm not sure why you think system is set up to hibernate.” - I have 2 decades of experience diagnosing Windows problems. Most modern systems are configured to hibernate rather than sleep due to hybrid hibernation support

Comment: Also *Start - Settings - Update and Security - Troubleshoot - Additional Troubleshooters* - and choose the *Power* one.

Comment: @CarlosN - Commentary is temporary.  This comment thread is to long and will be likely be cleaned up