# Why does "sleep" feature get affected every time if Windows 10 updates are not done properly?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sleep, updates

Recently, I updated my Windows with below update.

> [image]

Since then, my ["sleep" feature shuts down as explained in this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1651160/after-feature-update-windows-10-wont-sleep-powercfg-of-no-help) my laptop instead of going to "sleep".

Later, I uninstalled and reinstalled that update, and it fixed my "sleep" feature.

Why does "sleep" feature get affected every time if Windows 10 updates are not done properly?

Comment: There is certainly no point in posting anymore, useful answers notwithstanding

Comment: @John I don't get you.

Comment: I posted an answer that works for me and others I help but it was instantly downvoted and subsequently deleted. You may not be able to see the answer