# Does latest cumulative update of Windows 10 correct the broken one?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, updates, bug

Luckily I remember the date when I messed up Windows 10 update and
so [I fixed consequences by reinstalling that update](https://superuser.com/questions/1744803/why-does-sleep-feature-get-affected-every-time-if-windows-10-updates-are-not-d). Is it necessary to remember the date like this every time (or)
will the latest cumulative updates of Windows 10 correct the broken one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the latest cumulative updates of Windows 10 correct the broken
> one?

Generally yes.  Cumulative (and Feature update if one comes along for Windows 10) fix and update prior updates. Also new updates are issued that override older updates.

That said, it may depend upon the nature of the broken update.

I think it is fair to say that either (a) updates correct old updates (normal) or (b) you may need in some cases to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.